# easier way to find vowels and print them? JAVA

Tags: java, for-loop

Hey this is my first time posting! I got my program to print out the vowels from an input from user but I feel like I have repeated myself a lot in the for loop. Is there a quicker way to do this? Also is this code readable and in the correct format?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Task09 {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String vowels ="";

    //input from user
    String answer= input.next()

    //loop to find vowels

    for(int i = 0 ;i<answer.length();i++)
    {
        char answerPosition = answer.charAt(i);

        //checks if there are vowels in code
        if (answerPosition =='a'
                ||answerPosition  =='e'
                ||answerPosition  =='i'
                ||answerPosition =='o'
                ||answerPosition =='u'
                ||answerPosition =='A'
                ||answerPosition =='I'
                ||answerPosition =='O'
                ||answerPosition =='U')
        {
            vowels += answerPosition + " ";
        }

    }
            System.out.println("The vowels are:" + vowels);

    input.close();

}
```

}

Comment: Does your code work? No, it's not the cleanest code, but it's not bad for a newbie either. If it works for you, I'd say go with it.

Comment: There are no problems in your code (except a missing semicolon after `input.next`. Since you're seeking for ways to improve working code, then post your question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Sure you could use a fancy RegularExpression or some other method to do the same thing. But for this small example it is OK.

Comment: you can decalre vowels in a array .then ur code become smaller

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick input. I hope to be able to contribute someday lol. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  String newString = answer.replaceAll("[^AaeEiIoOuU]", "");
  System.out.println(newString);
```

You wont need for loop as well and your code would be compact and sweet.

Comment: I like it! so cool there is nearly a method made for everything!

Comment: For the regex, what are the [^] for? Are they something to do with arrays? Is the method replacing the vowels with a " "? how will that allow me to print out the vowels?

it says in the java website:

"Parameters:
regex - the regular expression to which this string is to be matched
replacement - the string to be substituted for each match"

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: it means not containing volwels (^ means not in)

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
if ( "aeiouAEIOU".indexOf(answerPosition) >= 0 ) {
    vowels += answerPosition + " ";
}
```

inside the loop.

Additionally, as a matter of style, you might write the iteration slightly differently:

```
for (char c: answer.toCharArray()) {
   if ( "aeiouAEIOU".indexOf(c) >= 0 ) {
      vowels += c + " ";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way too.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hi {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String vowels = "";

        // input from user
        String answer = input.next();

        // loop to find vowels

        for (int i = 0; i < answer.length(); i++) {
            char answerPosition = answer.charAt(i);
            char tempAnsPos = Character.toUpperCase(answer.charAt(i));

            // checks if there are vowels in code
            if (tempAnsPos == 'A' || tempAnsPos == 'E' || tempAnsPos == 'I' || tempAnsPos == 'O' || tempAnsPos == 'U') {
                vowels += answerPosition + " ";
            }

        }
        System.out.println("The vowels are:" + vowels);

        input.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: @Drejc: Damn COPY PASTE :). Correctd